# How is it possible to have an X-DNA/X-Match match on my father's side as a male myself?

Tags: dna, familytreedna.com, x-dna

On FamilyTree DNA, I have a match who is very clearly from my paternal grandfather's side.  I am a male myself and thought it was only possible to have X-DNA matches on my mother's side.  I thought my inheritance of X chromosomes follows the following pattern.

[image]

Comment: How large is the X segment that matches? Small segments could match by chance, and FTDNA does not filter out small segments that probably ought to be ignored.

Comment: Could there be two paths to reach your match? The "obvious" one and another via the maternal lineage?